# Superadditive games and the worth of the grand coalition

Tags: game-theory

I'm studying a first course in Game Theory, I don't understand why in superadditive games, the grand coalition has the highest payoff among all coalitional structures.

If by contraddiction we assume that in a superadditive game $(G,v)$ there exist $S\subset N$ such that $v(S)>v(N)$, then by superadditivity $v(N)\geq v(S)+v(N - S)>v(N)+v(N-S).$

Is there something that force $v(N-S)$ to be positive or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first answer, it was claimed that a super-additive game has only a non-negative range and that the grand coalition must have the greatest value. Both claims are not correct. Of course, if the game has non-negative coalition values, then the grand coalition must have greatest value. And yes, almost all relevant economical games are mapping into the non-negative range. However, the definition of super-additivity allows that the value of a coalition can be negative, but then the grand coalition cannot have anymore the greatest value. As a counter-example consider the following three-person game

$v(\emptyset)=0,v(\{1\})=-1,v(\{2\})=0,v(\{3\})=0,v(\{1,2\})=7,v(\{1,3\})=7,v(\{2,3\})=13,v(N)=12.$

This game is super-additive and the greatest value of $13$ is assigned to coalition $\{2,3\}$. Furthermore, the only convention imposed on a TU game is that the empty set will be assigned with the zero value.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, $v(S)\ge0$ for *all* subsets $S$ of $N$.

Comment: In zero sum coalitional game if $v(N)=0$, then for each subset $S$, it is the case that $v(N-S)\leq0$. Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Elia There is nothing wrong. If $v(N)=0$ then $v(S)=0$ if we assume superadditivity... no coalition gets any value and the situation is trivial.

Comment: Sorry but now there is another problem, and  without clarifying it I can't understand the whole argument. I've read the following in my book: "as the non cooperative case, the most commonly studied constant-sum game are zero sum games [Kevin Leyton Brown]". So I guess that there are games in which $v(N)=0$ and $v(S)\neq 0$. Now or all zero sum games are trivial as you wrote above, or there are other reasons to clarifying. Thank you

Comment: @Elia Superadditive games are not zero-sum games.

Comment: So in superadditive we require that $v:2^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_0^+$, while in zero sum $v:2^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Elia That is correct.